# Return type of printf() in C programing

Tags: c++, c

**A question regarding C Programming**
As we all know that printf() is a function to show the out on screen.

And we also know that every function has a return type.

So my question is that:

**What the default return type of printf() function ?**

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf, just look up such information by yourself since it's a pointless question.

Comment: Wow this question doesn't show any effort to solve the problem yourself!

Comment: What do you mean by *default* return type? A *return type* of `printf` in C is `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` returns number of characters successfully printed out.

The return type is `int`

Answer (score 2):

printf returns int. See this for [details](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

This is what it has to say

```
On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned.

If a multibyte character encoding error occurs while writing wide characters, errno is set to EILSEQ and a negative number is returned
```

Comment: You explained it quiet good. @almasshaikh

Answer (score 2):

int, it returns the number of characters that it has printed.